# Using Builder Lombok with enum in java

Tags: java, enums, apache-camel, quarkus

Good afternoon, I am currently working with quarkus and apache camen and I have a class called ContactMedium in which I must use enum called MediumType, as I show below:

```
package org.tmve.customer.ms.beans;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
@Builder
public class ContactMedium {

    public enum MediumType {
        TELEPHONE_NUMBER("telephone_number"), POSTAL_ADDRESS("postal_address");
        private String value;

        MediumType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    @JsonProperty("characteristic")
    private Characteristic characteristic;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I want to use the loombok generator, I can't find how to compile for the enum type parameter called mediumType and I don't want to use a plain string type variable:

[image]

The line that I am using to build is the following:

```
ContactMedium phoneNumber=ContactMedium.builder().
```

Is there a way to work with lombok builder and enum?

Comment: I do not understand the problem. The class `ContactMedium` has no field of type `mediumType`, thus there is nothing to set. Please [edit] the pot and clarify. --- As an aside: the enum `mediumType` should start with an uppercase letter (`mediumType` -> `MeditumType`).

Comment: I just edited my question, I clarify that I need to access or somehow set the enum MediumType field in the construction, however, I don't know if this is possible through the loobok builder

Comment: Again: The class `ContactMedium` has no field of type `MediumType`, thus there is nothing to set. This is not really related to lombok. I suspect that the class is simply missing a field of type `MediumType`.

Comment: And how do I add a field called Medium Type that is of type enum the ContactMedium class? Is this possible?

Comment: I never said you should add a field called `MediumType`, but of type `MediumType`. We can use enum types just like regular types. Just as we declare a field `String foo`, we can declare a field `MediumType foo`. I recommend reviewing/refreshing the language constructs before using advanced frameworks like lombok, jackson, ...

Comment: Declaring a nested `enum`, as you are doing, just creates the type, it doesn't create a field of that type in the enclosing class.

Comment: @tgdavies And how do I generate it in the attached class? Let it be a parameter that I can access in the construction

Comment: As @Turing85 said, just like any other field: `private MediumType myFieldName;`

Comment: And do things without lombok for now, you'll learn more.